# How to define prop types

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I am facing some trouble trying to define my static prop types in my React and Django application. In the documentation and in the tutorials I am watching they are defined as static propTypes with little p. However I get an error in my chrome console:

````
checkPropTypes.js:20 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `deleteLeads` is marked as required in `Leads`, but its value is `undefined`.```

When defining them with capital P (static PropTypes) I get another error:
````

react.development.js:167 Warning: Component Alerts declared `PropTypes` instead of `propTypes`. Did you misspell the property assignment?```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong when defining them. This is my code where I define them:

```js
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export class Alerts extends Component {
  static PropTypes = {
    error: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };
```

Comment: What tutorial are you watching? Use it the way it's shown here: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: Should be `static propTypes` for refrence on static and its use in React https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/understanding-static-in-javascript-10782149993

Comment: Ah okay. I fixed it after reading the documentation. Thank you very much!

Comment: [Rohit Chahal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12130130) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67037935) saying "prop-types useful for creating user-defined props for a component. This link may help you [https://blog.logrocket.com/validating-react-component-props-with-prop-types-ef14b29963fc/](https://blog.logrocket.com/validating-react-component-props-with-prop-types-ef14b29963fc/)"